# How to segregate file uploads to folders in Wix?

Tags: velo

I have setup a file upload for a form in WIX. My requirement is to create folders based on a particular field value used (a category dropdown), and then setup the upload to that folder. Is this possible on Wix? How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Looked into this myself, but unfortunately this isn't possible through Velo. I worked around it by storing the IDs of my uploaded files in a collection. The collection contains a JSON object which mimics the folder structure I actually wanted.

Answer (score -1):

This should be possible with a bit more work by using the wix-media-backend API, specifically the `upload()` function. When using that function, you can specify a folder in the path for the file name.

Comment: Not true - folders cannot be created dynamically, which is wat Kavinda is asking about. The wix-media-backend API requires you to create folders in advance.